# sending localhost ip to database in php and searching for it

Tags: php, mysqli, ip, localhost

I am getting server ip address in this method

```
$myip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $myip;
```

it echo out ::1

Then I am trying to sent this ip to database which I am sure this ip is already is in my db cause i write it there.

```
$result=mysqli_connect($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE IP=$myip");
```

Like i said i'm sure there is a IP=::1 section in my user list cause i wrote it there before. but every time it`s saying me query was empty what is the problem? And why it echo out ::1 from start then?

NOTE: I have wrote IP=10 section in my db then I sent `WHERE IP = 10` in query and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
$myip = $_SERVER['REMƠTE_ADDR'];
```

There is a typo in REMOTE_ADDR try this:

```
$myip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: and may I know what is the typo ?

Comment: The OP is already getting the right output as `::1` . That is IPv6 version which is equivalent to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I am writing via mobile and thats not the issue cause i get the ::1. just quessing may it be a problem because of ::?